# Where can I look for a co-author?

Tags: collaboration

I'm looking for a co-author to collaborate with me for a book. The ideas for the books I have are related to the topics romance, crime, and politics. I was wondering where can I find people that are interested in something like this but are not asking for money. I will share the royalities, profits with the co-author if we make money. I have talk to many people with the ideas I have in mind. They said they were all interesting idea and worthy of being published.

Comment: What sort of collaboration are you hoping for? Is it a split work load of each author writes 50% of the story or is it some other form. Is it you come up with the ideas and the other author writes the story around those ideas?

Comment: I can't answer the question as asked, so this is not an answer but an observation. This is unlikely to succeed if you have no track record, history or experience, and all you have to offer are 'ideas'. What random people say is worthy of being published doesn't matter, all the work is in the writing. It sounds like you are trying to get something valuable for free: ***here is my brilliant idea, now you, Mr. Writer, go figure out how this all works out, I will decide on any plot problems you encounter, now go do 99.9% of the work and I will give you half the money.*** That's ridiculous.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Writers. Just to be clear, this is not the right place to look for a co-author. It is the right place to ask what the right place is to look for a co-author.

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you're looking for a co-author, as opposed to writing it yourself? Without that, this just isn't enough information for us to give you a helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could try https://www.scribophile.com/. There are lots of writers on there and you may find someone who wants to work with you.

However, I'm concerned about what you mean by 'co-authoring'. Co-authors both write the book.

They could work in several ways - one doing the first draft, the other the editing, and back and forth.

Or they could each write different sections.

Possibly one could do a lot of the plotting groundwork, planning and character development and the other could write the actual prose.

However, contributing 'ideas' only would not (in my opinion) be considered co-authoring.

As someone has commented above, while ideas can be turned into something valuable, they are not worth much on their own. The value comes in the execution.

Not trying to put you off, just thought it was worth bearing in mind.

And if your ideas really are that good, perhaps you should have a go at writing them yourself - you might enjoy it : )